# Examples of categories which naturally include End(O) as object

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products, big-list

I want examples of categories $\textbf C$ which naturally include $End_{\textbf C}(O)$ as object for objects $O$ in the category. The set of all endomorphims is always a monoid under the composition of morphisms, but beside from that.

Counterexamples is also interesting.

I'm not asking for examples that has to be of interest from category theoretical point of view, but just natural examples where the structure of $O$ transfers to $End_{\textbf C}(O)$. The reason for my question is that I imagine some kind of correspondence between those categories and categories with tensor products, since there is a diagram that recalls about the universal property of tensor products:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X\times Y @>\mu>> End_\textbf C(X\times Y)\\
    @V \forall h V V\# @VV \exists\varphi V\\
    Z @= Z
    \end{CD}
$\mu(x,y)(a,b)=(x,y)$, $\varphi(f)=h\psi_{a,b}$ and $\psi_{a,b}(f)=f(a,b)$.

$\mu$ and $h$ are bi-morphisms and $\varphi$ is a morphism.

---

Examples:

- **Set**, $End(X)$ is trivially a set.
- $R$-**Mod**, $End(X)$ is a $R$-module:
  $(\alpha+\beta)(x)=\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$; 
  $(r\cdot\alpha)(x)=r\cdot\alpha(x)$ for commutative rings. For non commutative rings $End(X)$ is only a $\mathbb Z$-module.
- **Grp**, no obvious group structure on $End(X)$.
- **Top**, $End(X)$ is a topological space with the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: The $R-\mathrm{Mod}$ example works only for commutative $R$, right?

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit. And what about tensor products for non commutative rings?

Comment: If you do tensor product over a noncommutative ring, you take $M_R \in \mathrm{Mod}-R$ and $_RN \in R-\mathrm{Mod}$ (i.e. one right and one left $R$-module) to produce $M\otimes_{R}N$, which is an Abelian group in general, i.e. not necessarily left or right $R$-module. So the tensor product there is not a tensor product of a monoidal category.

Comment: @PavelC: Yes I remember know. And this speak for my hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

$End(O)$ is a set (or a monoid), it belongs to the category of sets and nothing else.

Perhaps you are interested in the notion of a [cartesian closed category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category). There one has an internal hom object $\underline{\hom}(x,y)$ for all objects $x,y$, in particular $\underline{\mathrm{End}}(x):=\underline{\hom}(x,x)$.

Comment: There are examples of End(O)-sets that naturally inherit the structure. Abelian groups I would say is an example, but not with the $\circ$ of course.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a self-enriched category, that is a monoidal category $\mathcal V$ which is the underlying category of a $\mathcal V$-category.

Any (symmetric) monoidal closed category is naturally self-enriched. Martin Brandenburg's answer is a special case (when the monoidal product is a cartesian one).

You might want to take a look at [Kelly's reprint](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf) in TAC.

Comment: I will check your link, but what I want is a big list of examples for common concrete categories (constructs).